# Слайдер: клон изображение на фон размытием

Tags: html, jquery, css, html5, css3

Дело в том что при листве фон изображение один и тотже остается как мне это сделать так чтобы изображение которое отображается клонировалась на фон с размытием?

Код:

```
.item:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;

  display: block;
  background-image: url('https://image-cc.s3.envato.com/files/33362626/wpthumbfx_preview_590x300.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Раз в вопросе указана метка jquery: вероятно, воспользоваться jQuery [методом](https://api.jquery.com/css/) и подменять `background-image`.

Comment: Да но изображение находется не на самом стиле а на before

Comment: точно, не заметил. Псевдоэлементы так, действительно, не обработать. Можно обернуть `.item` в div или span и *-filter с background применять к новому элементу. Тогда к элементу можно будет обратиться и подменить у него фон

Comment: Достаточно было создать отдельный див туда скопировать весь код от before таким образом далее проста на самом html указывать фон .Решил проблему.Спасибо за идею я чёто устал... ))